# Regular expression Contains at least 1 special character from the following set, or a non-leading, non-trailing space character

Tags: regex

Requirements: Regular expression Contains at least 1 special character from set, or a non-leading, non-trailing space character.

I am trying to write a regular expression for above requriements,
here is what i got so far:

```
[\^$*."!@#]| (\b\s+\b)
```

The above regular expression could successfully capture the character in the set, but it does not capture the non-trailing and non-leading empty space ,

Here is the [regular expression playground](https://regexr.com/6vle3)
However, this following regular expression can successfully capture the space i want , but when i use `|` to combine two expression , it does not work as expected.

```
\b\s+\b
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the result you want to get in the end? Do you mean the spaces must be enclosed with non-whitespaces, `[\^$*."!@#]|(?<=\S)\s+(?=\S)`?

Comment: hey wiktor, My main goal is to use this regular expression to check if the giving string either contains at least 1 special character from set or  at least one non-leading, non-trailing space character.

Comment: So, `[\^$*."!@#]|(?<=\S)\s(?=\S)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
[\^$*."!@#]|(?<=\S)\s(?=\S)
```

*Details*:

- `[\^$*."!@#]` - a `^`, `$`, `*`, `.`, `"`, `!`, `@` or `#` char
- `|` - or
- `(?<=\S)\s(?=\S)` - a whitespace that is both non-leading and non-trailing, since it must be enclosed with non-whitespace chars.